# Using AutoFilter in VBA to include all of Array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, autofilter

I am trying to filter out all PF, PG, PE from a column and enter into a new worksheet. The below code is only picking up PF, PG, PE but will not include when these are with anything else like PF,AT thats in the column as well. I need to have it filter on these 3 even when they are not just those three.

```
Sub SelfInstall()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    'declare variables to hold row and column numbers that define cell ranges -- DO NOT TOUCH
    Dim myFirstRow As Long
    Dim myLastRow As Long
    Dim myColumn As Long
    Dim mySourceWorksheet As Worksheet
    Dim orderSearch As Range
    Dim orderReturn As Range
    Dim orderCompare As Range
    Dim orderOutput As Range
    Dim mySourceData1 As String
    Dim mySourceData2 As String
    Dim mySourceData3 As String
    Dim mySourceData4 As String
    Dim jobtype As String
    Dim vlookupCol As Object

    Rows("1:1").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array("*PF", "*PE", "*PG", "PF*", "PE*", "PG*"), Operator _
    :=xlOr
    Cells.Select
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets("Self Install").Select
    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Selection.Columns.AutoFit
    Sheets("Sheet1").Select
    Range("A2").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData
End Sub
```

Comment: Use the `Advanced Filter` instead. Then you can have multiple wild-card criteria, instead of being limited to just 2.

Comment: Hello, yes I tried that with xlFilterValues and no luck.

Comment: I don't understand what you wrote. What does `xlFilterValues` have to do with `AdvancedFilter`?

Comment: I guess I do not understand the AdvancedFilter you are talking about with the criteria I have.     Selection.AutoFilter Field:=15, Criteria1:=Array("*PF", "*PE", "*PG", "PF*", "PE*", "PG*"), Operator _
    :=xlOr

Comment: See [Range.AdvancedFilter](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.advancedfilter). On the worksheet, you would select `Advanced Filter` from the Data tab. Use the `HELP` function to understand how it works on the worksheet. That will help you understand how it will work for you in VBA code.  As a matter of fact, set it up first on the Worksheet so you can see that it is working.